# User immediately logged out after logging in after mistakenly typing `startx`

Tags: xubuntu, xfce, gui

This question is very similar to a few others on this site, but I don't think identical to any; please hear me out.

I've had Xubuntu installed for a few weeks now, but today I accidentally pressed <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F6</kbd> while doing work while logged in under XFCE. [This dropped me into a terminal environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/120296/used-ctrl-alt-f6-in-linux-and-cant-get-my-screen-back), which surprised me. I'd never seen this happen before.

Panicking, I hastily typed `sudo startx` to get back to an X session, which dropped me into a root session. That too, for some reason, shocked me, so I shut down the computer.

Upon booting back up again and trying to log into my XFCE session like usual, I was logged in to a black screen for a fraction of a second and then logged back out again, dropped into the XFCE login screen. This behavior is repeated no matter the number of full reboots performed.

I believe this is an issue with how XFCE is now configured, but I don't know what to do. I have very little experience dealing with X session configuration. Does anyone know what might be happening here?

**EDIT:** I have already tried removing the `~/.Xauthority` file and rebooting. No improvement, the issue has persisted.

**EDIT 2:** I'm running Xubuntu 18.04. Output of `~/.xsession-errors`

```
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=unix:path=/run/user/1000/bus
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting DISPLAY=:0
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting XAUTHORITY=/home/neil/.Xauthority
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting QT_ACCESSIBILITY=1
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting LANG=en_US.UTF-8
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting GDM_LANG=en_US
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting DISPLAY=:0
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting XDG_GREETER_DATA_DIR=/var/lib/lightdm-data/neil
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting USER=neil
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting DESKTOP_SESSION=xfce
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting PWD=/home/neil
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting HOME=/home/neil
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting QT_ACCESSIBILITY=1
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting XDG_SESSION_TYPE=x11
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting XDG_DATA_DIRS=/usr/share/xfce4:/usr/local/share:/usr/share:/var/lib/snapd/desktop
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting XDG_SESSION_DESKTOP=xfce
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting SHELL=/bin/bash
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting XDG_SEAT_PATH=/org/freedesktop/DisplayManager/Seat0
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting IM_CONFIG_PHASE=1
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP=XFCE
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting GPG_AGENT_INFO=/run/user/1000/gnupg/S.gpg-agent:0:1
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting SHLVL=1
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting LANGUAGE=en_US
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting GDMSESSION=xfce
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting LOGNAME=neil
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=unix:path=/run/user/1000/bus
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/run/user/1000
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting XAUTHORITY=/home/neil/.Xauthority
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting XDG_SESSION_PATH=/org/freedesktop/DisplayManager/Session0
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting XDG_CONFIG_DIRS=/etc/xdg/xdg-xfce:/etc/xdg
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting _=/usr/bin/dbus-update-activation-environment
xfce4-session: Unable to access file /home/neil/.ICEauthority: Permission denied
```

Comment: Running `startx` is fine - running `sudo startx` is the problem, it has likely left you with a root-owned `~/.Xauthority` file which your XFCE session is now unable to overwrite. You will need to log into the terminal environment (e.g. Ctrl-Alt-F6) again and delete the file (`rm ~/.Xauthority`).

Comment: @steeldriver would the `.Xauthority` file be in my home directory or `/home/root/`? I have since deleted the `/home/neil/.Xauthority` a couple of times, to no avail upon restart.

Comment: I'm not even sure what `/home/root` would be - if you have already deleted the file in your own home directory, then please ignore my comment (although you might want to [edit] your question to include this information, since it will stop others from making the same assumption)

Comment: Thank you for trying to help, @steeldriver. My idea of `/home/root` comes from the Raspberry Pi, which I believe at one point featured a root home directory.

Comment: Is there an `.xsession-errors` file? Have you checked its contents? What version of Xubuntu is this?

Comment: Updated my question with the requested file. I'm running Xubuntu 18.04.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ah, that's it! Thank you, @steeldriver for the debugging tip. As per `~/.xsession-errors`:

`xfce4-session: Unable to access file /home/neil/.ICEauthority: Permission denied`

Upon removing `~/.ICEauthority`, login works like a charm again. I suspect that my prior removal of the `~/.Xauthority` file was also critical to the resolution of this issue even though it didn't appear so initially.